# PyQT — переключение между несколькими окнами браузера (WebKit)

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt4

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь создать приложение, внутри которого можно будет переключаться между, допустим, 4-мя окнами браузера по нажатию соответствующей окну кнопки. Необходимо, чтобы неактивные окна просто скрывались, без "уничтожения".

За любые указания хотя бы в нужную сторону поиска -- заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Эм, а что запрещает QWidget::hide() использовать?

Answer (score 1):

то есть своего рода, часть панели задач, а точнее тот трей в котором приложения показываются.

Если абстрагироваться от визуализации то тут останется класс, в котором список открытых окон, и из этого списка берем только последние (или первые или по алфавиту) 4 записи.

А пример создания такой панели по моему даже где то в туториале самого QT должен быть!